# Refresh listView with multiple view types after delete/remove item

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` and has 2 view types. When I run my `adapter.removeRow(position)` method, the data for the adapter is correctly updated, and the list reflects this, but the view types are not correctly updated. The Adapter is backed by

`ArrayList<Map<String, String>> rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();`

and I have a subset

`List<Integer> flashSet = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

which is a list of all the positions that are of ViewType 1 (as opposed to the standard view type 0).

Here is my adapter `removeRow(position)` method:

```
    public void removeRow(int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_FLASH) {
            flashSet.remove(position);
        }
        for (int flashPosition:flashSet) {
            System.out.println(tag+"is "+flashPosition+" going to be moved?");
             if (flashPosition > position) {
                 flashPosition -= 1;
                 System.out.println(tag+"Yes! It's been moved to "+flashPosition);
             }
        }
        rows.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Here is my `getView` method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        FlashHolder flashHolder;
        ClipHolder clipHolder;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            if (type == TYPE_CLIP) {
                convertView = rowInflater.inflate(R.layout.clip_note_row_layout, null);
                clipHolder = new ClipHolder();
                flashHolder = null;
                clipHolder.textView = (TextView)(convertView.findViewById(R.id.clip_text));
                convertView.setTag(clipHolder);
            } else {
                convertView = rowInflater.inflate(R.layout.flash_row_layout, null);
                clipHolder = null;
                flashHolder = new FlashHolder();
                flashHolder.front = (TextView)(convertView.findViewById(R.id.flash_text));
                flashHolder.back = (TextView)(convertView.findViewById(R.id.clip_text));
                convertView.setTag(flashHolder);
            }
        } else {
            if (type == TYPE_CLIP) {
                clipHolder = (ClipHolder)convertView.getTag();
                flashHolder = null;
            } else {
                clipHolder = null;
                flashHolder = (FlashHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
        }
        if (type == TYPE_CLIP) {
            clipHolder.textView.setText(rows.get(position).get("clip"));
        } else {
            flashHolder.front.setText(rows.get(position).get("flash_text"));
            flashHolder.back.setText(rows.get(position).get("clip"));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

I know that I could create a new `adapter`, give it the updated `ArrayList` and call `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` but this seems total overkill when I'm simply trying to remove one item from a potentially long list. See pics for a before and after deleting:
[image: Before]

Then I delete the first item. The word "which" was hidden behind the "Let's watch it" item and now the "inspired by…" item is hidden behind a blank item 3.

[image: After]

So, data is updating, view types aren't. Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 for the look and feel of the app and good explaination of the issue

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know when it's released if you're interested.

Comment: Have you overriden `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` methods in your adapter?

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the issue. See my answer below. Pure stupidity on my part and it took putting a question up here for me to figure out where I was going wrong.

Comment: And I can see inconsistency in your `{` and `}` in `getView()` method. Please update your question if its not a coding fault.

Comment: Done, thanks. I stripped a few clauses out in the online editor here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. This will be useful to no one as I don't expect others to make the same mistake.

I naively thought that by doing this

```
    for (int flashPosition:flashSet) {
        System.out.println(tag+"is "+flashPosition+" going to be moved?");
         if (flashPosition > position) {
             flashPosition -= 1;
             System.out.println(tag+"Yes! It's been moved to "+flashPosition);
         }
    }
```

I was changing the actual value stored in the `List<Integer> flashSet = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

In fact, I need to do the following instead:

```
for (int flashPosition:flashSet) {
    System.out.println(tag+"is "+flashPosition+" going to be moved?");
     if (flashPosition > position) {
         flashSet.remove((Object)flashPosition);
         flashPosition -= 1;
         flashSet.add(flashPosition);
         System.out.println(tag+"Yes! It's been moved to "+flashPosition);
     }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have `ArrayList<MyListData>`. `MyListData` being an abstract class and having an `int type;` variable. Now you will just need different concrete implementations. This way you can have as many `View` types as you want in your `ListView`, without having to manage complex and slow mechanisms for maintaining indices. E.g. in your `getItemViewType()` I guess you rely on `List.contains()` method whereas in above approach you can just call `return rows.get(position).type`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `List.contains()`. I see what you mean. It's a good idea. Do you think it would offer performance improvements or do you just think it's more elegant. I'll implement it if I need a third view type. Thanks.

Comment: `contains()` method takes `O(n)` time to find an item. `getIteViewType()` is called many times when user scrolls through `ListView` and every time `contains()` method iterates over your flasSet which consumes more resources, in my opinion. That's what I am saying. Its better to write flexible code first time instead of coming back and changing the whole code just because you want to add headers or fancy lines at some places in your `ListView` :)

Comment: Also using this approach you can have totally different data types for each row of your `ListView` as well, not just `String`s. One row could contain small `Bitmap` while other is a combination of `boolean` and `String`s etc.

Comment: Point taken. Implementing now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, After delete or add item you need to call adapter refresh.

```
Youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `yourlistview.invalidateViews()`

instead of

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same same result.